# Json doesn't work. geojson / getproperty / array and addListener

Tags: jquery, geojson

My geoJSON looks like this:

```
worldmap_callback({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "id": 0, 
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [7.7457704, 51.6738374]
        },
        "properties": {
            "products": [{
                "name": "Pocan&reg;", 
                "link": "link1"
            }, {
                "name": "Whatever&reg;", 
                "link": "link"
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

I want to fetch it like this:

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var buildText = event.feature.getProperty("products[name]").join("<br />");
    infowindow.setContent("<div class='maps-info'>" + buildText + "</div>");
    infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
    infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)});
    infowindow.open(map);
});
```

At the end it should look like this:

```
buildText<a href='link1'>Pocan&reg;</a></div>
```

What do I do wrong / how is this done?

THANKS A BUNCH!

Comment: Well. I helped myself and now here we go: 

`var buildText = event.feature.getProperty("products").map(function(item){
     return "<a href='" + item.link + "'>" + item.name + "</a>";
    }).join("<br />");`